# Are these independent events? How do I find P(B)?

Tags: probability

30% chances A fixes his computer.
If A cannot, then 40% chances B fixes A's computer.
I am required to find probability that computer is fixed by either A or B.

Using this relation
$P\left( {A \cup B} \right) = P\left( A \right) + P\left( B \right) - P\left( {A \cap B} \right)$

Do I take A and B as independent events?
Because there is no ${A \cap B}$, as B occurs only when A fails.

I know,
$P\left( A \right) = 0.3$, and 
$P\left( {B|{A^C}} \right) = \frac{{P\left( {B \cap {A^C}} \right)}}{{P\left( {{A^C}} \right)}} = 0.4$

Also, How do I go about finding $P\left( B \right)$?
what's $P\left( {B \cap {A^C}} \right)$ in the problem?

The solution is 0.58. If I take this into account and the fact from first comment that these are mutually exclusive events, then 
$P\left( B \right)$ = 0.18. How?

Comment: Those two events are *mutually exclusive*, which is  very different from independent.

Comment: You can also think about this intuitively. Independent means "information about one event **does not** change our beliefs about the other event". We know that if $A$ fixes his own computer, then $B$ will not fix the computer. Here, information about the first event DOES change the information about the second event, and thus they are not independent.

Comment: Why aren't they independent? Def "Independent events are events where knowledge of the probability of one doesn't change the probability of the other" How A and B are related? I mean their probabilities, remains same. Isn't it?

Comment: Or do I take it as occurrence of one has no effect on occurrence of other? for independent event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already observed that $P(A\cap B)=0$, since they cannot both repair the computer. If you apply the the independence definition in formulas, i.e., $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ you would arrive immediately at $P(A)P(B)=0$ such that either $P(A)=0$ or $P(B)=0$. The first one is not possible since $P(A) = 0.3$ and you have already observed that $P(B|A^c)>0$ such that $P(B)\neq 0$. Thus, they are not independent.

I guess your $P(B) = 0.18$ is wrong since $$P(B)=P(A\cap B) + P(A^c\cap B)= P(B|A^c)P(A^c) = 0.4\cdot 0.7=0.28$$ and the result follows by $P(B\cup A) = P(A)+P(B)=0.28 + 0.3 = 0.58$.

Comment: All I needed to think about was this, $P(B)=P(A\cap B) + P(A^c\cap B)= P(B|A^c)P(A^c) = 0.4\cdot 0.7=0.28$$. I was complicating my calculations. Thanks @Jfischer.